# jQuery accordion menu and auto height

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have jQuery accordion menu. With the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/eXKEB/

Everything is working, no problem. But my list is too long. So, i want when click `caption` get content with auto height.

So, i want auto height option in my js code. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem?  Sorry but I am not understanding your requirement 100%.  Please reword or expand your question.

Comment: Are you looking for the list, when it displays, to have its own scrollbars? Or should the list be cut off -- what ever it takes to fit on the screen?

Comment: @Chris i want this. Click a element and see it. http://bit.ly/LENhia

Comment: You have one big table, your example has several small lists. You need to break your list up into smaller sections.

Comment: @Chris updated link http://jsfiddle.net/eXKEB/